# How to deploy a nodejs app to heroku with github

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

i want to deploy this application https://github.com/thefailtheory/neofreelance i am developping on my http://livecoding.tv channel
to heroku but i am facing an error

the application is basic it will try to solve a problem on freelancing in the cloud i use everyday

here is the log :

```
2016-11-22T16:20:34.454131+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

2016-11-22T16:20:34.454297+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! neofreelance@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`

2016-11-22T16:20:34.454450+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1

2016-11-22T16:20:34.454616+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 

2016-11-22T16:20:34.454772+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the neofreelance@1.0.0 start script 'node app.js'.

2016-11-22T16:20:34.454931+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.

2016-11-22T16:20:34.455081+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the neofreelance package,

2016-11-22T16:20:34.455232+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.

2016-11-22T16:20:34.455378+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:

2016-11-22T16:20:34.455537+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node app.js

2016-11-22T16:20:34.455684+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:

2016-11-22T16:20:34.455833+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs neofreelance

2016-11-22T16:20:34.456007+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:

2016-11-22T16:20:34.456156+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls neofreelance

2016-11-22T16:20:34.456302+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

2016-11-22T16:20:34.459887+00:00 app[web.1]: 

2016-11-22T16:20:34.460174+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

2016-11-22T16:20:34.460356+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: You have no `Procfile`?

Comment: i have deployed an app via dropbox it worked without it, i should have one with nodejs ?

Comment: It is working but I don't think it's safe to rely on default behaviors (i.e. Heroku will by default run `npm start`).

Comment: i don't know too i am trying heroku with node these day because it's really funny to play with this kind of technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because Block-scoped declarations (`let`, `const`) are not yet supported in the Node version Heroku is using outside of strict mode.

So two options:

- Add `"use strict";` at the beginning of your file
- Use `var` and not `let`.

Comment: `let` worked fine with another project and a deployment with dropbox, so i am going to try the first option

Comment: oh i see it's you use `var` and without `use strict` it works or you add `use strict` and you can code with `let`

Comment: Yes. Or maybe you can [specify a Node version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version) that would accept `let` without strict mode. I don't know if Heroku would have it though.

Comment: i would stay in simple way and use `var` but `let` gives a certain style in the code like avoiding `;` or give a try to a specific version of node should be a nice feature to test

Comment: FYI: [ES6 features implemented in last versions of Node.js](http://node.green) and [versions of Node Heroku supports](https://semver.io/node/versions)